# Display XML in Android development

Tags: android, xml, rss

I am writing a RSS reader on Android and this need to parse XML data.I want to know what is your method to display XML data in Android development? I think use WebView's loadData is a simple method. Can I find another simple way to display it?

Comment: i think you want to xml parsing in android?

Comment: Eclipse has a built-in XML editor. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Little bit confusion you want to parse xml and display data or you want to display xml formatted data

Comment: Sorry for the description and now it has been refreshed.

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya I think xml parsing is a bit complex and I want to find a simple way

Comment: please see i had posted link below and this is very easy step by step xml parsing code

Comment: @Pratik The former but I don't want to use SAX or other complex method,I want to find a simple way or a built-in widget.

Comment: I think SAXParser is simplest way